# How to hide php codes and mysql table schema

Tags: php, mysql, encryption, schema, hide

We've a Clint requirement in which, all the PHP source codes + MySQL DB will be in their network. So all their data will not be visible to outside world. That's we can do.

But, the thing is.. we want to hide our source codes(PHP) & MySQL DB from them(client). So that no body can make any miss use of those.

For PHP i think "ZEND GUARD" will be a good choice. But, still.. i want to know is there any other better tools available in web for hiding PHP source codes.

About, hiding MySQL DB.. we've no idea how to deal with this. But, more specifically we want to hide our all tables SCHEMA. So that, no body can access all those information.

Any idea guys..

Regards

Comment: "we want to hide our source codes" from whom?? from company from end users? ..folder permissions/mysql privileges/access control ????

Comment: With Zend Guard you can "compile" your php but with the mysql database if they want to get in and they control the box its on they are going to get in.

Comment: @swapnesh
That's from our 'client'. Because, they want.. we deploy our application in their network. Rather than any hosting public hosting provider.

Comment: Usual paid php script are protected with IonCube (http://www.ioncube.com/).

Comment: @Orangepill 
About "Zend Guard" i've not any details idea. Just i went through their online documentation only.

Comment: @mi6crazyheart which OS they are using?

Comment: @Kevin How 'IonCube' is better than 'Zend Guard'? Coz, 'Zend Guard' is a free one. But, 'IonCube' is a paid one.

Comment: Just set up a folder which only you guys have access to? Same for DB make a mysql account that only you guys have the username and password for...

Comment: Are you providing a configured MySQL instance? Or are you running on whatever local MySQL instance is provided my the local admin?

Comment: @JasonSperske  We've planned to setup & deploy(LAMP stack) a server in their(client) campus/network. But, this server will have provision for us to access it from our office.

Answer (score 0):

For php codes you can write some dll files which contain your functions and that is how you can code them. for that see [here](http://php.webtutor.pl/en/2011/07/07/how-to-create-php-extensions-in-c-part-i-adding-simple-function/)

and for your mysql you can put it on another server and give access to people you need.by the way you can make as many users in a db as you want and give them the specific accesses. for that see [here](https://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/788/HOWTO%3a+GRANT+privileges+in+MySQL)